# pgsql Рrint the result of select to output

Tags: postgresql, output

Recommend please the pgsql construction for this case, i need to print the list of id in this select to output

select id from dq.'||l_table_name||' group by id having count(1)>1 limit 10

Comment: Could you share the DDL for the table involved, some data, and some expectations for the output?

Comment: What is `pgsql` referring to,  the command line client `psql`, the language `plpgsql` or something else?

Comment: pgsql, exuse me.

Comment: You just repeated what is in your question, so again  **`psql`**, **`plpgsql`** or something else?-